# Construction of Compact Boundary-Corrected Scaling Functions

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, wavelets

I'm trying to construct the (left) boundary-corrected Daubechies scaling function, following the article

> A. Cohen, I. Daubechies, P. Vial. "Wavelets on the Interval and Fast Wavelet Transforms". 1993.

The authors say, that "plots have again been obtained via the cascade algorithm", but my tries fail and I can not get the plots of Fig. 6 on page 23 by myself.

The way, I'm trying to do it, is first analytically to get the values of $\phi^{left}(t)$ in all integers. Having this vector of values, one can easily compute the values in all binary rationals using the presented construction
\begin{align*}
\phi^{left}(t) = \sqrt{2} \sum^{N - 1}_{l=0} H^{left}_{k,l} \phi^{left}(2t-l) + \sqrt{2} \sum^{N + 2k}_{m=N} h^{left}_{k,m} \phi(2t-m),
\end{align*}
where $\phi$ is known "usual" (not boundary-corrected) Daubechies Scaling Function translated by $-N+1$ such that $supp(\phi) = [-N+1, N]$. Moreover, we assume that the coefficients $H^{left}_{k,l}$ and $ h^{left}_{k,m}$ are known. One can show that $supp(\phi^{left})=[0, N + k]$.

But here is my problem with this approach: Let, for example, $N=2$ and $k=0$, so that
$$\phi^{left}(t) = \sqrt{2} H^{left}_{0,0} \phi^{left}(2t) + \sqrt{2} H^{left}_{0,1} \phi^{left}(2t - 1) + \sqrt{2} h^{left}_{0,2} \phi(2t-2).$$

Then we start with the system $\phi^{left}|_{\mathbb{Z}}$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi^{left}(0)\\
\phi^{left}(1)\\
\phi^{left}(2)
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2} H^{left}_{0,0} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sqrt{2} H^{left}_{0,1} & \sqrt{2} H^{left}_{0,0}\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\phi^{left}(0)\\
\phi^{left}(1)\\
\phi^{left}(2)
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
\sqrt{2} h^{left}_{0,2} \phi(0)\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $H^{left}_{0,0}=0.6033325119$, $H^{left}_{0,1}=0.6908955318$ and $h^{left}_{0,2}=-0.3983129977$. The system has a solution
$$\phi^{left}(0) = 0; \;\;\; \phi^{left}(1) = \frac{\sqrt{2} h^{left}_{0,2} \phi(0)}{1 - \sqrt{2} H^{left}_{0,1}} = -33.56346328045783; \;\;\; \phi^{left}(2) = 0,$$
what is obviously wrong based on the graph bellow (Fig.6 in (1) on page 23):

[image]

Any help or even idea how to construct this scaling function would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a misprint in my formula. The correct form (corresponding to the formula from the article) is
\begin{align*}
\phi^{left}_k(t) = \sqrt{2} \sum^{N - 1}_{l=0} H^{left}_{k,l} \phi^{left}_l(2t) + \sqrt{2} \sum^{N + 2k}_{m=N} h^{left}_{k,m} \phi(2t-m).
\end{align*}
This equation is quite easy to solve directly.